# Python find word occurences in list of phrases and link word to phrases

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Let's say, I have a `.txt` file with phrases divided by new line (`\n`)

I split them in list of phrases

```
["Rabbit eats banana", "Fox eats apple", "bear eats sanwich", "Tiger sleeps"]
```

---

**What I need to do:**

I need to make `list of word objects`, each word should have:

1. name
2. frequency(how many times it occured in phrases)
3. list of phrases it belongs to

For word `eats` the result will be:

```
{'name':'eats', 'frequency': '3', 'phrases': [0,1,2]}
```

---

**What I've already done:**

Right now, I am doing it simple, but not effective:

I get the list of words(by splitting `.txt` file by space character (" ")

```
words = split_my_input_file_by_spaces
#["banana", 'eats', 'apple', ....]
```

And loop for every word and every phrase:

```
for word in words:
    for phrase in phrases:
       if word in phrase:
          #add word freq +1
```

---

**What is the problem with current aproach:**

I will have up to 10k phrases, so I encountered some problems with speed and performance.  And I want to make it faster

I saw this interesting and promising way of counting occurences(but I don't know how can make a list of phrases each word belongs to)

```
from collections import Counter
list1=['apple','egg','apple','banana','egg','apple']
counts = Counter(list1)
print(counts)
# Counter({'apple': 3, 'egg': 2, 'banana': 1})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're referring to (the interesting and promising way of counting occurrences) is called a HashMap, or a dictionary in Python. These are key-value stores, which allow you to store & update some value (such as a count, a list of phrases, or a Word object) with constant time retrieval.

You mentioned that you ran into some runtime issues. Switching to a HashMap-based approach will speed up the runtime of your algorithm significantly (from quadratic to linear).

```
phrases = ["Hello there", "Hello where"];
wordCounts = {};
wordPhrases = {};

for phrase in phrases:
    for word in phrase.split():
        if (wordCounts.get(word)):
            wordCounts[word] = wordCounts[word] + 1
            wordPhrases[word].append(phrase)
        else:
            wordCounts[word] = 1
            wordPhrases[word] = [phrase]

print(wordCounts)
print(wordPhrases)
```

Output:

```
{'there': 1, 'where': 1, 'Hello': 2}
{'there': ['Hello there'], 'where': ['Hello where'], 
    'Hello': ['Hello there', 'Hello where']
}
```

This will leave you with two dictionaries:

- For each word, how often does it appear: `{word: count}`
- For each word, in what phrases does it appear: `{word: [phrases...]}`

Some small effort is required from this point to achieve the output you're looking for.